# PHP nginx mysql: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www-git/www1/api/credentials/mysql.php on line 12

Tags: php, mysql, nginx

I have installed mysql-server php5-mysql and nginx. When I execute a script (by webrequest) it outputs the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www-git/www1/api/credentials/mysql.php on line 12
```

This tells me that mysql api cannot be found, I guess. I have restarted nginx.

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

checked php.ini for any msql related settings(found none but this could maybe be the error)
I also ran this(without really knowing why it initiates the dbs I guess so I do not think its important):

```
sudo mysql_install_db
```

I don’t know what to look for in phpinfo(), I checked but found nothing relevant.

Why can't PHP, in my current nginx setting, find mysql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using PHP-FPM:

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

PHP ran in its own process. Nginx configuration has nothing to do.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to restart that one